# Getting error while setting image from parse to imageview

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-viewholder

I am using holder to set images from Parse to my image view, below is following code

```
holder.rank.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getRank());
holder.country.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getCountry());
holder.population.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPopulation());
holder.flag.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getFlag()));
```

And below is the error given by android studio

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "http://listview123.herokuapp.com/parse/files/hlkhlkhyuiyemnbbmbackguyweuiyqw/10ad83c5546b993c18be84402e0f2bff_android_1.png"

Answer (score 0):

You can't just say "*here is the url of the image, do something*"

You have to download the image and set is as the wanted resource.

**For a guide look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)**

Or if you want to use an external library you could, like Azmat said, use Picasso

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageURL).into(myImageView);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot M4lik.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load images from link

```
Picasso.with(context).load(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getFlag()).into(holder.flag);
```

p.s: this code works if your worldpopulationlist.get(position).getFlag() returns link for file.

Comment: Thanks a ton azamat.